# Xpath to extract email from Trip Advisor

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

Hi I have a page that I want to extract the email from and it is protected by onclick so import.io isn't recognizing it. I want to use Xpath to extract the email and use the same for all other pages. Please recommend the best method.

Trip Advisor: 
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g1064230-d8541936-Reviews-Yog_Bluffin-Alicante_Costa_Blanca_Province_of_Alicante_Valencian_Country.html

The code that I want to use xpath on:

```
<div class="taLnk fl" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Eatery_Listing', 'Email', 8541936, 1);
                       return ta.call('ta.locationDetail.checkEmailAction',event,this,'info@yogbluffin.com',
                              8541936,
                              '\x41\x6e\x20\x69\x6e\x71\x75\x69\x72\x79\x20\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x20\x61\x20\x54\x72\x69\x70\x41\x64\x76\x69\x73\x6f\x72\x20\x75\x73\x65\x72\x20\x66\x6f\x72\x20\x59\x6f\x67\x26\x61\x6d\x70\x3b\x42\x6c\x75\x66\x66\x69\x6e',                                   'Restaurant_Url_');">
```

What is the best method to extract the email using Xpath?

Comment: My code: //div[@class='taLnk fl'] //div[contains(@class, '@')

Comment: I guess you should use `//div[@class='taLnk fl']` `XPath` to select required element and then use `reg-ex` to parse value of `onclick` attribute

Comment: Andersson, thanks for quick reply, i'm trying this in with the developer tool in chrome, if done correctly it should highlight what i want. Could you please help me out with the complete code for this?

Comment: Actually have no idea how to get email manually from dev tools. You can use something like `cUrl` to scrape web-page and then parse it with proper regular expression

Comment: i'm just using chrome to test if the xpath points to the correct location, i'm using import.io for the scraping and they have an xpath option - i'm just going through trial and error since each time my xpath is wrong.